# Ajuda em NullPointer Exception

Tags: java, jsf, nullpointerexception

Antes dos dados irem pro banco estou com um `nullpointer` que já *debuguei* e não encontro onde está o problema. Abaixo minhas classes:

```
package br.com.pokemax.controle;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import br.com.pokemax.modelo.Habilidade;
import br.com.pokemax.negocio.HabilidadeDAO;

@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "habilidademb")
public class ControleHabilidade implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private Logger log;
    private Habilidade habilidade;
    private HabilidadeDAO dao;

    private Boolean habilidadeHidden;

    public Habilidade getHabilidade() {
        return habilidade;
    }

    public void setHabilidade(Habilidade habilidade) {
        this.habilidade = habilidade;
    }

    public Boolean getHabilidadeHidden() {
        return habilidadeHidden;
    }

    public void setHabilidadeHidden(Boolean habilidadeHidden) {
        this.habilidadeHidden = habilidadeHidden;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void novo() {
        habilidade = new Habilidade();
    }

    public void gravar() {
        FacesMessage facesMsg;
        try {
            if (habilidade.getId() == null) {
                dao.insert(habilidade);
                facesMsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Gravação realizada com sucesso!", "");
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("messagePanel", facesMsg);
            } else {
                habilidade = dao.update(habilidade);
                facesMsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Registro Atualizado com sucesso!", "");
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("messagePanel", facesMsg);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            facesMsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Erro:" + e.getMessage(), "");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("messagePanel", facesMsg);
            log.warning("Erro: " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

Modelo:

```
package br.com.pokemax.modelo;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

@Entity
@Table(name="tb_habilidade")
public class Habilidade implements Serializable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(length=20,nullable=false)
    private String nome;

    @NotNull
    @Column(length=150,nullable=false)
    private String descricao;

    @Column(name="efeito_secundario")
    private String efeitoSecundario;


    public Habilidade() {
    }



    public Habilidade(String nome, String descricao, String efeitoSecundario) {
        super();
        this.nome = nome;
        this.descricao = descricao;
        this.efeitoSecundario = efeitoSecundario;
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }


    public String getEfeitoSecundario() {
        return efeitoSecundario;
    }


    public void setEfeitoSecundario(String efeitoSecundario) {
        this.efeitoSecundario = efeitoSecundario;
    }


    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }



    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((descricao == null) ? 0 : descricao.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((efeitoSecundario == null) ? 0 : efeitoSecundario.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((nome == null) ? 0 : nome.hashCode());
        return result;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Habilidade other = (Habilidade) obj;
        if (descricao == null) {
            if (other.descricao != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!descricao.equals(other.descricao))
            return false;
        if (efeitoSecundario == null) {
            if (other.efeitoSecundario != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!efeitoSecundario.equals(other.efeitoSecundario))
            return false;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        if (nome == null) {
            if (other.nome != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!nome.equals(other.nome))
            return false;
        return true;
    }




}
```

DAO:

```
package br.com.pokemax.negocio;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import br.com.pokemax.modelo.Habilidade;

@Stateless
@LocalBean  
public class HabilidadeDAO implements DAO<Habilidade,String>{

    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;

    @Inject
    private Logger log;


    @Override
    public Habilidade insert(Habilidade t) throws Exception {
        log.info("Persistindo " + t);
        em.persist(t);
        return t;
    }

    @Override
    public Habilidade update(Habilidade t) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Habilidade delete(Habilidade t) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Habilidade find(String k) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Habilidade> findAll() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<ui:composition template="/layout/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form>
            <p:panel header="Cadastrando Habilidades">
                <p:messages />
                <h:panelGrid id="cadastro" columns="3">
                    <h:outputLabel value="Nome: " />
                    <p:inputText id="nome" value="#{habilidademb.habilidade.nome}" size="20" />
                    <p:message for="nome" />
                    <h:outputLabel value="Descrição: " rendered="true" />
                    <p:inputTextarea id="descricao"
                        value="#{habilidademb.habilidade.descricao}" rows="6" cols="20" />
                    <p:message for="descricao" />
                    <h:outputLabel id="efeitoS" value="Possui efeito secundário? : " />
                    <p:selectBooleanButton id="efeito"
                        value="#{habilidademb.habilidadeHidden}" onLabel="Sim"
                        offLabel="Não" style="width:60px" />
                    <p:message for="efeito" />
                    <h:outputLabel value="Efeito Secundário: "
                        rendered="#{habilidademb.habilidadeHidden == true}" />
                    <p:inputTextarea id="secundario"
                        value="#{habilidademb.habilidade.efeitoSecundario}" rows="6"
                        cols="20" rendered="#{habilidademb.habilidadeHidden == true}" />
                    <p:message for="secundario" />
                    <p:commandButton action="#{habilidademb.gravar}" value="Salvar" update="cadastro"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

Classe Util:

```
package br.com.pokemax.util;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;


public class JPAUtil {

    @Produces
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Produces
    public Logger produceLog(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        return Logger.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());
    }

}
```

Estou tentando debugar mais este caso, observei que quando chega na classe DAO, ele lê a linha:

```
log.info("Persistindo " + t);
```

Depois ele já cai no `catch`. O erro mostrado na console é:

> 13:33:20,806 WARNING [br.com.pokemax.controle.ControleHabilidade] (default task-8) Erro: null

Comment: Onde está essa linha?

Comment: @diegofm próximo do try na classe Controle.

Comment: @Douglas A resposta resolveu o que procurava saber? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora? Se não, precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Você pode aceitar qualquer uma delas, inclusive a sua.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o que era, observando o debug, notei que o dao estava null, então usei a Injeção nele ao invés de instanciar ele, fazendo isso funcionou.

```
@Inject
HabilidadeDAO dao;
```

Answer (score 4):

Não sei se é suficiente mas algo pode resolver é mudar esta linha:

```
private HabilidadeDAO dao = new HabilidadeDAO();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/Initialization.java).

Para ajudar mais precisaria de mais contexto.

O código estava acessando a propriedade sem inicializá-la. Isto faz a inicialização. Se é o jeito certo de fazer eu não sei, depende do seu código.

Depois da edição ocorre o mesmo problema na variável `em` e deve ser solucionada da mesma forma. Isto vai acontecer com todas variáveis não inicializadas. Então sugiro aprender sobre o funcionamento de variáveis que é um conceito bem básico, antes de tentar fazer qualquer coisa mais complexa. Enquanto não dominar isso estará só preenchendo lacunas e não programando de fato.

O objetivo do site não é jogar os erros para os outros corrigirem, é resolver dúvidas quem possam ajudar a todos. Além disso o problema da pergunta foi resolvido, não adianta ficar editando e colocando novos erros idênticos. Nem acho adequado colocar uma pergunta para cada erro de *null reference* que aparecer no código. Pra falar a verdade considero esta pergunta duplicada de várias outras que já foram respondidas antes sobre a mesma coisa. O problema é recorrente porque as pessoas não aprendem o básico. [A maioria é duplicata](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nullpointerexception).

Nem falei sobre exceções usadas da forma errada porque não está no escopo da pergunta e é um assunto mais complexo. Deixo uma [lista de perguntas que podem ajudar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:101%20%5Bexce%C3%A7%C3%A3o%5D), mas eu sei que ninguém lê e continua fazendo errado.

Comment: Não resolveu, o que mais gostaria que eu postasse?

Comment: "Não resolveu" não ajuda muito, você poderia discorrer mais sobre isto. programação não é funcionou ou não, é entender o que está acontecendo, é detalhar o problema. Sem isso, eu não sei dizer o que mais deve colocar. É provável que o erro tenha mudado, mas é necessário dar informações. Todo programador deve entender o que é necessário para entendimento do problema, caso contrário não está programando. Veja: [mcve].

Comment: Adicionei mais informações.